# Displaying Single Output Based on a Number Range (if, goto)

Tags: batch-file

Can someone please explain to me why this won't display only the result for the number between the range given in the `if` command? No matter what I've tried, it continually displays all of the results, despite the range given. I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855529/if-number-is-at-certain-range-do-command-here) already, but it doesn't work. If I write `if %ans% LEQ 8 GOTO :2` for example, it'll display all the results for all numbers less than 8, rather than just between 5 and 8 (which is what I'm trying to display for).

```
set num1=%1
set num2=%2
set /a ans=num1+num2

if %ans% LEQ 4 GOTO :1

if %ans% GTR 4 if %ans% LEQ 8 GOTO :2

if %ans% GTR 8 if %ans% LEQ 16 GOTO :3

if %ans% GRT 16 if %ans% LEQ 32 GOTO :4

:1
echo # Host Req     #   Mask   #       Netmask      #   Max Supported #
echo   %ans%            /30            255.255.255.252      4
echo.

:2
echo # Host Req     #   Mask   #       Netmask      #   Max Supported #
echo   %ans%            /29            255.255.255.248      8
echo.

:3
echo # Host Req     #   Mask   #       Netmask      #   Max Supported #
echo   %ans%            /28            255.255.255.240      16
echo.

:4
echo # Host Req     #   Mask   #       Netmask      #   Max Supported #
echo   %ans%            /27            255.255.255.224      32
echo.
```

Comment: You can eliminate the need for the second if by reversing your tests (16, 8, 4, etc.).

Comment: The command processor runs line to line, unless something tells it not to. At the end of each section, `:1`, `:2` and `:3`, you need to instruct the command processor to `GoTo` somewhere, probably `:EOF`, which means, end of file; you could of course just use an `Exit /B` command there instead. In order to read any intened output, it may be wise to precede that with a `Pause` in order to give time to read it first. Please also note your typo, `GRT` instead of `GTR`.

Comment: Oh wow, that's all it was. Figures. I tried it out -- it works. And better yet, it eliminates the need for the second if. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off

set /a ans=%1+%2

for %%n in (4 8 16 32) do if %ans% LEQ %%n GOTO :%%n

echo %ans% is greater than 32
goto :EOF

:4
echo # Host Req     #   Mask   #       Netmask      #   Max Supported #
echo   %ans%            /30            255.255.255.252      4
echo.
goto :EOF

:8
echo # Host Req     #   Mask   #       Netmask      #   Max Supported #
echo   %ans%            /29            255.255.255.248      8
echo.
goto :EOF

:16
echo # Host Req     #   Mask   #       Netmask      #   Max Supported #
echo   %ans%            /28            255.255.255.240      16
echo.
goto :EOF

:32
echo # Host Req     #   Mask   #       Netmask      #   Max Supported #
echo   %ans%            /27            255.255.255.224      32
echo.
goto :EOF
```

Comment: That's even better! Another question (seeing as you're already familar with my code) -- is it possible to log the date and time when this kind of application is executed? I know that you can't log the output and display the output with cmd. But is it possible at least with the date and time? I've come across multiple answers and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [IPv4 CIDR Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks) your `max supported`values are wrong:

> In common usage, the first address in a subnet, all binary zero in the host identifier, is reserved for referring to the network itself, while the last address, all binary one in the host identifier, is used as a broadcast address for the network; this reduces the number of addresses available for hosts by 2.

Batch is capable of doing bitmask and shift operations to calculate the required values and thus eliminating the need for different tables.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\31\SO_50615266.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set num1=%1
set num2=%2
set /a ans=num1+num2

for /l %%L in (2,1,8) do (
    set /a "Max=(1<<%%L)-2, Mask=32-%%L, OC4=254-Max"
    If !Max! geq %ans% (
        echo(## Calculated on %computername% by %username% at %date% %time:~0,8%
        echo # Host Req     #   Mask   #       Netmask      #   Max Supported #
        echo   %ans%            /!Mask!            255.255.255.!OC4!      !Max!
        echo(
        Goto :Eof
    )
)
Echo %ans% exceeds a class D net
```

Sample ouput:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\05\31\SO_50615266.cmd 1 1
## Calculated on HP-G1610 by LotPings at 2018-05-31 18:37:06,77
# Host Req     #   Mask   #       Netmask      #   Max Supported #
  2            /30            255.255.255.252      2


> Q:\Test\2018\05\31\SO_50615266.cmd 14
## Calculated on HP-G1610 by LotPings at 2018-05-31 18:37:38
# Host Req     #   Mask   #       Netmask      #   Max Supported #
  14            /28            255.255.255.240      14
```

Comment: According to your comment to aschipfls answer, added a date/time stamp.

Comment: In reference to the CIDR chart, I had to copy a chart that was given to me, and it includes both the NID and BID as hosts in this case. Your calculations are impressive! I assumed there was an easier way to get there (versus writing out each line manually). Thank you.